# quasicrystal and penrose tiling, mathematical introduction

Tags: reference-request, tiling

Starting to research on quasicrystal from material science, I want to know more about how to   understand quasicrystal from a purely mathematical (especially tiling) perspective (probably start from Penrose tiling). I am more familiar with Wang Tile from my previous experience, do you have any suggestion on where shall I start reading on this topic? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two recommendations:

> Senechal, Marjorie. *Quasicrystals and geometry*. Cambriged Univ Press, 1996.
>   Review by Charles Radin in the *AMS Notices*: [PDF download](http://www.ams.org/notices/199604/radin.pdf).
>   
>    
>    
>    
>   [image]

---

> Baake, Michael. "A guide to mathematical quasicrystals." *Quasicrystals*. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2002. 17-48. ([arXiv prepub link](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9901014).)
>   
>    
>    
>    
>   [image: Fig.13.2]
>   
>   Maximum entropy equals $\frac{1}{3} \log 2$.

Answer (score 7):

If you really aim for substantial mathematical facts I also recommend "Aperiodic Order" by Baake and Grimm. (My account is so new that I cannot "comment" or "Vote up" or something.) The first 6 or 7 chapters are easy to understand for anyone with some basic knowledge on calculus and algebra. The next chapters are tougher. Already in the first 6-7 chapters you learn a lot not only on tilings but on all the relevant mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best advice is to contact Marjorie Senechal at smith.edu (her email name is just her last name), since she has written and reviewed quite a few papers in this area.   See for example an older expository note [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0898122189901430) and its references.   Though she has recently retired from teaching, she is well-connected with the subject and the people involved.

There are many technical papers on quasicrystals, not all useful for a newcomer and not all readily accessible online.  I'm not aware of good introductory sources at the textbook level, but I'm certainly not a specialist in this area.   Marjorie might be helpful in figuring out what you need to look at first.

Answer (score 4):

The newly published "Aperiodic Order Volume 1. A Mathematical Invitation" by Baake and Grimm is also good. More daunting than Senechal's book, but clearly written and comprehensive.